# Selecting Records As Paired Parent Child

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Records are being saved as parent-child in the same table linked with `pairkey` column and then even parents are divided into two legs linked with `scndleg` column. That is, there will be two parent legs interlinked with `scndleg` column and each parent will have children having `seqnno` of parent in `pairkey` column.

Look at this [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3b010/2)

I need to select one complete batch as

```
Both legs of interlinked parents
UNION
All children of these two parents
```

and then the other batch following same pattern and so on shown in the [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3b010/2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit** New version of the query (link to SQLFiddle at the end):

```
SELECT
    seqnno,
    narration,
    pairkey,
    scndleg
  FROM (
    SELECT p.*, LEAST(seqnno, scndleg) related_leg_min_id
      FROM pairs p
  )
START WITH scndleg IS NOT NULL
CONNECT BY pairkey = PRIOR seqnno AND scndleg IS NULL
ORDER BY connect_by_root(related_leg_min_id), scndleg DESC NULLS LAST, pairkey
;
```

Output:

```
    SEQNNO NARRATION                   PAIRKEY    SCNDLEG
---------- ------------------------ ---------- ----------
         1 1st leg parent                    1          4 
         4 2nd leg parent                    4          1 
         2 1st leg child                     1            
         3 1st leg child                     1            
         5 2nd leg child                     4            
         6 2nd leg child                     4            
         7 another 1st leg parent            7         10 
        10 another 2nd leg parent           10          7 
         8 another 1st leg child             7            
         9 another 1st leg child             7            
        11 another 2nd leg child            10            
        12 another 2nd leg child            10
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3b010/22)</kbd>

Comment: No, 1st 2nd leg Parents will be together and then their children and then another 1st and 2nd leg parents and their children...

Comment: @bjan Then can you provide sample output that you expect? Cause I can't figure it out based on you description...

Comment: There is a query in Query Panel of the referred fiddle, run and see the results

Comment: @bjan My query returns the same result set. I guess what you need is that the output will be sorted like in your example? Meaning, firstly parents, then children?

Comment: @bjan and can children nodes have children and so on?

Comment: @bjan Ok, I've edited my answer with new version of the query, please take a look.